# How to set SCSS Variable by selector

Tags: html, sass

I try to set different background color to namespaces, for that I use css variables and classes like this

*CSS*

```
body.workspace {
  $backgroundColor: #f1f4fa !default;
  &.admin {
    $backgroundColor: #e4daec;
  }
}
```

*HTML*

```
<body class="workspace #{namespace}">
  ...
</body>
```

And namespace is set to `admin` if needed

But `$backgroundColor` is all the time set to #e4daec independently of the class is admin or not

Maybe I have to use 2 différents variables ?

Comment: It would be the perfect moment to use css custom properties instead of scss variables.

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that sass variables are resolved during compile time (so the actual runtime nesting is unknown). You can accomplish what you are trying to do with css variables, as @AmauryHanser has already pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options. You can use two different varibles:

```
$backgroundColor_one: #f1f4fa;
$backgroundColor_two: #e4daec;

body.workspace {
  background-color: $backgroundColor_one;

  &.admin {
    background-color: $backgroundColor_two;
  }
}
```

or you can use a @mixin with if statement something like this:

```
@mixin backgroundColor($val){
    @if $val == one {
      color: #f1f4fa;
    }
    @else if $val == two{
      color: #e4daec;
    }
  }

body.workspace {
   @include backgroundColor(one);
   
   &.admin{
     @include backgroundColor(two);
  }
}
```

if body element has only workspace class like this:

```
<body class="workspace"></body>
```

The bg color should be #f1f4fa. But if  tag has two classes like this:

```
<body class="workspace admin"></body>
```

The bg color should be #e4daec

Comment: That doesn't solve anything; it just complicates setting hardcoded background colors. If that is what the OP wants he can just use `body.workspace { background: #f1f4fa; }` and `body.workspace.admin { background: #e4daec; }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes but, I use to use my background variable in many different Classes so the best way is to set like this ?

```
body.workspace{
  &.admin2 {
    .wrapper{
      background-color: $backgroundColorAdmin;
    }
    #sidebar{
      background-color: $backgroundColorAdmin;
    }
    #main-navbar{
      background-color: $backgroundColorAdmin;
    }
   ...
   ...
  }
```

In fact, it works well